# Notification receiver failed to catch the GCM message in particular devices

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging, aes-gcm

When am receiving GCM Notification am getting the below error log.

**W/GCM-DMM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent {act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=****** (has extras) }**

Condition:
1. At the time my application is not in background and foreground also.

How do i resolve the problem. Please help somebody.﻿

Comment: Show us your code and check weather your token is valid or not ?

Comment: @RakshitNawani This is happening in some devices only but am receiving notifications perfectly with other devices.